# General solution of given first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the general solution of given equation:
$$
 pz - qz = z^2 + (x + y)^2 ,~~p=\frac{∂z}{∂x},~q=\frac{∂z}{∂y}
$$
I got one solution $ x + y = c$ , $c$ is  a constant.  What is  the other solution. Please help.

Comment: This is a partial differential equation?

Comment: Yes it partial differential equation.

Comment: In what variables? Are $p, q, z$ functions of $x$ and $y$? I do not see any partial derivatives in the equation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your equation is linear, you can determine the characteristic curves by solving
$$
\dot x=a(x,y,z)=z\\
\dot y=b(x,y,z)=-z\\
\dot z=c(x,y,z)=z^2+(x+y)^2
$$
or
$$
\frac{dx}{z}=-\frac{dy}{z}=\frac{dz}{z^2+(x+y)^2}
$$
As you found, the first two equations combine to $$x+y=c_1.$$  Combining the first and third equations gives $$\frac{zdz}{z^2+c_1^2}=dx\implies z^2+c_1^2=c_2e^{2x}.$$

With $c_2=\phi(c_1)$ you get the general solution as $$z=\pm\sqrt{\phi(x+y)e^{2x}-(x+y)^2}$$

Comment: Thank you Lutzl.